# Error RC1017: invalid integer constant expression (WIN_CE to WIN32)

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, windows-ce

I receive this error when i try to compile a VC++ project for WIN32 platform on Visual Studio 2008.
Compiling for a WIN_CE platform is ok.

> fatal error RC1017: invalid integer constant expression   C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\winuser.rh

The interested line of winuser.h file is this: **#if(_WIN32_WCE >= 0x0500)**

```
#if(_WIN32_WCE >= 0x0500)
#define DS_USEPIXELS        0x8000L
#endif
```

I'm using these preprocessor definitions:

```
WIN32
CORECOMMON_EXPORTS
_WINDOWS
_DEBUG
_USRDLL
$(ARCHFAM)
$(_ARCHFAM_)
STANDARDSHELL_UI_MODEL
```

What i'm missing?

Comment: Clearly `_WIN32_WCE` should **not** be defined when you don't target WinCE.  How this happened is not obvious from the question, consider a text search on all the files in your project directory.

Comment: I think that preprocessor definitions for resource compiler (the tool used to process rc files) are different from those of the C/C++ compiler. Did you check the rc command line?